# How to assign a macro to a button in a new excel workbook VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

my code is originally run from an Excel template that generates a new workbook with a button. My desire is to have that button be able to run it's own code without referencing to the original template so that anyone from my company can open up the new workbook and press the button to have the code to work no matter who opens the new workbook. The issue is the new workbook name changes dynamically depending on the customer's name (which pulls from a cell).

Right now I have the code exist inside one of the newly created sheets ("Tariff Page") called "Button_Click" (This sheet and code is copied right from the template).

I'm not sure the easiest way to get the button to call on the code in the new workbook sheet without it referencing the old template, since nobody else will have that as it's saved to my computer. If I manually assign the code to the button it works fine, but other people won't know how to do that.

This code exists on the template. When the button is pressed it references the template and not the new sheet code

```
Sub saveRatesFile()

With ActiveSheet

Sheets("Tariff page").Activate

    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(700, 10.5, 173.25, 41.25).Select
    Worksheets("Tariff Page").Buttons("Button 4").Text = "Save as PDF"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 4")).Select
    Selection.OnAction = "Sheet2.Button_Click"

End With
 
End sub
```

[image: This is where the code currently exists]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```vb
Sub saveRatesFile()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Tariff page")
    
    With ws.Buttons.Add(700, 10.5, 173.25, 41.25)
        .Text = "Save as PDF"
        .OnAction = "'" & wb.Name & "'!Sheet2.Button_Click"
    End With
 
End Sub
```

Comment: This was the answer, Tim thank you so much! I spent far too much time struggling when the answer was this easy ._.